# How do I make a "PocketPal" in Minecraft as a pet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

it's StickyChannel92 for another question.

How can I make a custom pet in a custom shape that follows me around? I want to be creative with not only with armor stands, but programming them to do certain things. I want something like this: (on the left next to me)

[image: Starbot]

Can I achieve this sort of goal **without using any plugins**? All I know is that this is a Vanilla Minecraft server, and they make these sort of "PocketPals". How can I make one?

Comment: That's probably two player heads stacked on each other or a texture pack that automatically downloaded onto your game.

Comment: No, it's not a texture pack, but I think it involves armor stands and player heads. BTW, the bottom part literally rolls, like how that same robot acts like in Star Wars.

Comment: Even if it isn't a texture pack, in any case, you yourself could use a server texture pack. It would probably be less of a hassle than dealing with invisible armor stands.